# Restrict Android Flurry SDK from getting phones sensitive data

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

An Android application I'm developing keeps getting rejected from some China stores with the reason that "Flurry SDK is reading sensitive data like IMEI/MAC info etc." that's forbidden based on their policy. Is there any way to enable it for crashlytics purposes only and avoid collecting this kind of data? By deleting the SDK my app gets approved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did it say what exactly sensitive data Flurry collected? Flurry does collect Android ID and Google Ad ID (if app permits).

Comment: Scenario: App shows the collecting rules, but collect the IMEI, Mac address, installed app list, contacts, calling history and sms without permission.
Scenario: SDK is collection contacts, sms, calling history in the background.

Comment: This is the message they're rejecting with @Po-Ting Wu